# Where are hotspots in GCC/CLANG?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, clang, compiler-optimization

I want to test GCC/clang and I want to focus on parts that most computations/optimizations happens there. What are those files?

Comment: I think you need to expand on what you mean by hotspots here. Are you talking about "hotspots" in the compiler's code itself, or in the code that compiler is compiling? To what end do you want to know this?

Comment: [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) are two different compilers, with very few (and probably almost none) common code.

Comment: @RossRidge I mean compiler itself.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, That's right. If you have suggestions on any of them, I appreciate it.

Comment: I think the best answer with such little information is "all of the files"... Find a `gcc-<some-version>.tar.gz`, unpack it, and start digging around. Various portions of the compilation process, from input parsing, syntactical analysis, semantic analysis, optimizations, restructuring, reorganization, code generation, etc. are going to be scattered all over the place in the source code - there isn't one single file that contains "most computations/optimizations", or even a small subset of files. Compilers with mature optimization frameworks tend to be very complex creatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't find any blatant hot spot in the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (there have been some GSOC project around that idea a few years ago), at least when you ask it to optimize.

You could use the [`-ftime-report` & `-fmem-report`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) options to `gcc` (in addition of optimizing options like `-O2`) to find out more which (compiler optimization) passes is using time. For most workloads, you won't find any blatant passes eating a lot more resources than others.

I guess it is the same in Clang. Compilers are very complex software, and there is no easy hot-spot to optimize inside them (otherwise, people within the compiler community would have found them).

BTW, recent GCC have plugin hooks, which enable you to code your GCC plugin (in C++), or your GCC extension (in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) to find more.